# How to replace a string of dots with a character at a specific position in java?

Tags: java, string, replace, position, stringbuilder

I'm currently learning Java and one of the exercises is to write a method that prints a line of dots (like ...........) and replaces one of the dots with a different character (like #).
The method takes two int values, the first one determines the length of the printed line, the second one the position at which the # should be.
So it should look like this depending on the int values: ....#......

Here's what I've tried so far. I tried using a StringBuilder in order to use .setCharAt because I thought I could then just type in at what index to replace the string with the # symbol. I know that I would need to tweak the position variable to get the desired position, because indexes start counting at zero, but for the time being that's irrelevant.
This sounds like something that an array should be used for, however we haven't gotten around to discuss arrays in the course, so there has to be a way to solve this without using an array.

`

```
static int printSingleDot(int length, int position) {
        String line = ".";
        String linelength = line.repeat(length);
        StringBuilder dot = new StringBuilder(linelength);
        dot.setCharAt(position, '#');
        System.out.print(dot);
        return length + position;
    }
```

`

Comment: I would suggest you to repeat the dot "position" times, then append the hashtag, and then repeat the dot again for "length - position - 1" times. You may concatenate using the string builder, or directly concatenating pure strings

Comment: Your code seems to be working as you specified; https://www.jdoodle.com/iembed/v0/zrc

Answer (score 0):

This methods returns the computed String and for later use. Actually, I didn't know String#repeat(int) method, thanks for that.

```java
    static String printSingleDot(int length, int position) {

        if(length <= position) {
            return "#";
        }

        return new StringBuilder()
                .append(".".repeat(position))
                .append("#")
                .append(".".repeat(length - position - 1))
                .toString();

    }
```